# Why mysql gives result with postfix zeros

Tags: mysql

Columnname **CallDuration**
Values like 35,59,59 etc no zero or null at present.

> datatype for column 'CallDuration' is INT(11)

but when i run this query

```
SELECT AVG(CallDuration),
       SUM(CallDuration)/COUNT(*) AS `Time` 
FROM cdr;
```

result is displayed as

```
51.0000
```

Why ? Any help.

Comment: whats your datatype ?

Comment: datatype for column 'CallDuration' is INT(11)

Comment: changing type to varchar gives correct result as **51** but when i use sec_to_time, like `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(CallDuration)),SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CallDuration)/COUNT(*)) AS `Time` FROM cdr;`. It gives result as **00:00:51.000000**

Comment: try changing INT(11) to INT(5)..and see the result

Comment: @utility - same result. no change still getting 51.0000.well using round gives correct result.

Comment: Why is this a problem- or are you just trying to improve your understanding of the inner workings of MySQL (a dangerous place to go)

Comment: @Strawberry - in case of int type result was postfixed with zero.but changing it to varchar gave correct result.but when i cnverted same result to time.again postfix zeros.

Comment: That doesn't really address my comment. And frankly converting to time or VARCHAR is bonkers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ROUND in this query like

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CallDuration)),
   SUM(CallDuration)/COUNT(*) AS `Time` 
   FROM cdr;
```